# Find last index of element in string with regular and remove substring

Tags: javascript, string

I have an array of strings. i am using regular i am trying to find index of occurrence of element and remove substring from string but i have problem when i add another occurrence of character

My solution:

```
const names = [
  'COMMENT — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
  'CODE| COUNTRY | DATE |TARGET',
  'CODE|| COUNTRY| DATE |TARGET',
  'COMMENT 1 — COMMENT 2 — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
];

const exp = new RegExp(/—|-/);

const filteredNames = names.map(name => {
  const index = name.match(exp)?.index;
  return name.slice(index + 1)
});

My result:

"CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET"
"CODE| COUNTRY | DATE |TARGET"
"CODE|| COUNTRY| DATE |TARGET"
"COMMENT 2 — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET" <- not correct
```

But expected result:

```
"CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET"
"CODE| COUNTRY | DATE |TARGET"
"CODE|| COUNTRY| DATE |TARGET"
"CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET"
```

I shall be most grateful for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last element, you can split on either type of hyphen and get the last part:

```js
const names = [
  'COMMENT — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
  'CODE| COUNTRY | DATE |TARGET',
  'CODE|| COUNTRY| DATE |TARGET',
  'COMMENT 1 — COMMENT 2 — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
];
const regex = /[—-]/;

names.forEach(s => {
  const parts = s.split(regex);
  console.log(parts[parts.length - 1].trim());
})
```

For a bit more performant match, you can use an optionally repeated group:

```
\w+(?:\s*\|+\s*\w+\s*)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\s*\|+\s*\w+\s*` Match 1 or more pipes and word chars between optional whitspace cars
- `)*` Optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E1ww5M/1).

```js
const names = [
  'COMMENT — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
  'CODE| COUNTRY | DATE |TARGET',
  'CODE|| COUNTRY| DATE |TARGET',
  'COMMENT 1 — COMMENT 2 — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
];
const regex = /\w+(?:\s*\|+\s*\w+\s*)*$/;

names.forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[0])
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try a regex replacement approach here:

```js
var names = [
  'COMMENT — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
  'CODE| COUNTRY | DATE |TARGET',
  'CODE|| COUNTRY| DATE |TARGET',
  'COMMENT 1 — COMMENT 2 — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
];
var output = names.map(x => x.replace(/(?:.*? — )*([^ |]+)/g, "$1"));
console.log(output);
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used here:

```regex
(?:.*? — )*  match (but do not capture) a "TERM — ", zero or more times
([^ |]+)     then capture the final term in $1
```

Then, we replace each pipe delimited entry with `$1`, the final term.

Answer (score 1):

You can just select part which you need:

```js
const names = [
  'COMMENT — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
  'CODE| COUNTRY | DATE |TARGET',
  'CODE|| COUNTRY| DATE |TARGET',
  'COMMENT 1 — COMMENT 2 — CODE | COUNTRY | DATE | TARGET',
];

const exp = new RegExp(/(\w+(\s*\|*\s*))*\w+\s*$/g);

const filteredNames = names.map(name => {
  const matches = name.match(exp);
  return matches?.[0] || '';
});

console.log(filteredNames);
```